# APB is congruent to DPC. Find $x$

Tags: geometry

I wrote in $x+23$ for DPC but then I'm stuck heres the image since I can't embed:

APB is congruent to DPC.

APB is $x+23$

BPC is $x$

BPD = $4x - 39$

Which can be seen here:
[image]

Comment: Please, explain your problem. Write all details.

Comment: Edited and explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: BPC + CPD = BPD. So we have that $2x + 23 = 4x - 39$. Solve for $x$.

Comment: So..... x = 31.

Comment: @Michael I believe that is the case.